# Excel code to sum the last 7 cells in a row but if one of the values is 0 reset and start adding cell rows to the right as entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Excel Office 365. Col A = Total hours Col B Name Col C-Y head.Date/Day entered hours worked. I am trying to sum  the latest seven days hours entered and totaled in column A. I have completed this step. The difficulty I'm having is that if the hours entered in columns C-Y is equal to zero I need to reset the Total Hours and start adding the hours on the next cell.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,COUNTA(C$4:CC$4),1,-7))
```

## sum the hours from the most recent entries.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: some sample data and expected result with clear explanations will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the full range so I am assuming that you are looking for the last 7 cells in the not blank area. Try this one:

`=IF(SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,COUNTA(C$4:CC$4),1,-7))=0, 0,SUM(OFFSET(B4,0,COUNTA(C$4:CC$4),1,-7)))`

Hope it helps

Comment: David thank you for your code which works fine but I'm looking for one more piece that I am having difficulty with. I'm trying to sum the last seven days or until a "0" is entered.